# Vue3 - OnBefoureRouteLeave does not wait for user input

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router

I need to create an onBeforeRouteLeave function to wait for user input. The problem is that the unsaved changes confirmation dialog appears, but nothing happens when clicked. When I debugged the program, I found that after the dialog was displayed, the onBeforeRouteLeave function had already finished long ago, so it doesn't matter what the user clicks. How do I create this function correctly?

Here is my code
**Template**

```
<q-dialog v-model="unsaveGridDialog" persistent>
    <q-card>
        <q-card-section class="row items-center">
            <q-avatar icon="save" color="primary" text-color="white" />
            <span class="q-ml-sm">Are you want to leave bage without saving your grid?</span>
        </q-card-section>

        <q-card-actions align="right">
            <q-btn @click="unsaveCancel = true" flat label="No" color="primary" v-close-popup />
            <q-btn @click="unsaveConfirm = true" flat label="Yes" color="primary" v-close-popup />
        </q-card-actions>
    </q-card>
</q-dialog>
```

**onBeforeRouteLeave**

```
onBeforeRouteLeave((to, from, next) => {
    showUnsaveDialog()
        .then(() => {
           next();
         })
         .catch(() => {
           next(false);
         });   
});
```

**showUnsaveDialog()**

```
function showUnsaveDialog() {
    unsaveGridDialog.value = true;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const checkUserInput = () => {
            if (this.unsaveConfirm) {
                resolve();
            } else if (this.unsaveCancel) {
                reject();
            } else {
                setTimeout(checkUserInput, 100);
            }
        };
        checkUserInput();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your showUnsaveDialog function, you forgot to return the promise, like so:

```js
onBeforeRouteLeave((to, from, next) => {
    return showUnsaveDialog()
        .then(() => {
           next();
         })
         .catch(() => {
           next(false);
         });   
});
```

Comment: It's the same. I'm debugging my program using breakpoints and the "onBeforeRouteLeave" function jumps to the "catch" branch and then a dialog pops up. So when I click the button nothing happens

Comment: You didn't tell at first you were reaching catch. In that case, you can know what the exception is by writing `catch(e)`. Inspect e. When trying to repro your exact code, I noticed that you had `unsaveGridDialog.value` (without this) and `this.unsaveConfirm` and `this.unsaveCancel`. Are you sure you need `this`? In my case, I'm using Vue with Composition so there this is no `this` in script setup. Anyway, the exception will tell you what bad thing happened. On my side, your exact code, with syntaxt corrected (`this` removed and `.value` added on both variables) works as expected.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Problem was mixing "this" and ".value". It's working after replace "this" with ".value".